# Nested navigation click logic issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to get a simple vertical navigation to display a list item's children on click.

However when you then click any of those nested, children list items you are in essence 'clicking' the parent list item again. Which triggers my click function to remove '.active' and closes the parent list item right before the user is redirected to their chosen page. This looks bad and is totally annoying.

Any advice on how to get a click function to not affect the children list items?

```
$('#sidebar > li.parent').click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
      }else{
        $(this).addClass('active');
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<aside id="tertiary" class="tertiary">
    <ul id="sidebar" class="sidebar">
        <li class="active"><a href="/">Portal</a></li>
        <li><a href="ecards.html">Start Here</a></li>
        <li><a href="ecards.html">Cards</a></li>
        <li class="parent"><a href="programs.html">Programs</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">LOS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Safety</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Retirement</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Wellness</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Investors</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Marketplace</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reporting</a></li>
    </ul>
</aside>
```

Comment: Add either `return false` or use `.stopPropagation()` and bind that to the children.

Comment: @j08691: `return false` would also have stopped the links from working.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - You do see that the child links are just `#`?

Comment: @j08691: Yes... you will stop those `bookmark` links from working :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a click handler for the child elements that uses `stopPropagation`to prevent the click event bubbling to parent elements:

```
$('#sidebar > li li').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Further reading: [MDN docs for `Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event).

Comment: You would need to stop propagation in the children... not the parent

Comment: Hmm this is a new concept to me. How would I stop propagation on the children?

Comment: This solution may work for you in this case at this time but I would seriously consider checking out my answer below, and the included link for an explanation.  I'm also including a fiddle for proof it works as intended.

Answer (score 4):

You would need to stop propagation in the children... not the parent

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/g6a496Lf/

```
$('#sidebar > li.parent').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
}).find("ul li").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();    
});
```

The `e.preventDefault()` is just there to stop the link clicking on the parent in the example. `e.stopPropagation()` stops the child click bubbling up the DOM.

I chained the two handlers together, so that you did not need a separate selector like this:

```
$('#sidebar > li.parent ul li").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();    
});
```

Comment: That first e.preventDefault breaks the initial click functionality.

Comment: @BenRacicot: Hence saying it was just for the example... *Take it out* :)

Answer (score 1):

Before you stop propagation of events, take some time to spin up on [why you shouldn't do so](http://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/).

From css-tricks.com, "The Dangers of Stopping Event Propagation", *very* briefly:

"Modifying a single, fleeting event might seem harmless at first, but it comes with risks. When you alter the behavior that people expect and that other code depends on, you're going to have bugs. It's just a matter of time."

"A much better solution is to have a single event handler whose logic is fully encapsulated and whose sole responsibility is to determine whether or not the menu should be hidden for the given event."

With that being said, you could do something like

```
$('#sidebar').on('click', function( e ) {
    var $target = $(e.target).closest('li');

    if ( $target.hasClass('parent') ) {
        $target.toggleClass('active');
    }
});
```

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/g6a496Lf/1/

Comment: You link is already dead (from here at least) :( Best copy some of the relevant content when it is working.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I've tried a few times now, and it works for me, but I will add the content... thanks!